# JQL Query for tickets created during and after business hours over the last 6 months

Tags: jira, jql

I would like to show tickets created over a running 6 month period during and after business hours but I can't seem to get the 6 month period to work

project = XXXX AND createddate >= (-180d) AND created > startofDay("+6h") AND created < startofDay("+18h")

Answer (score 0):

I think I would use an external script and the Jira REST API to retrieve all the issues' created date. Then parse the dates. If different users have different time zones that could be tricky too